# How to use tableView.row with NSStoryboardSegue

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to send details from selected cell in a `NSTableView` to another ViewController.

I have a button:

```
@IBAction func detailButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetailsVC", sender: self)
}
```

And a prepare for segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let row = self.tableView.row(for: sender as! NSButton)
    if segue.identifier == "toDetailsVC" {
        
        let destination = segue.destinationController as! DetailsVeiwController
        destination.name = orders[row].name!
    }
}
```

The error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Test.ViewController' (0x100022b98) to 'NSButton' (0x7fff8b59b260).

When I check `let row = self.tableView.row(for: sender as! NSButton)` inside the button, it works fine.
Am I way off here? Where is this going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is the view controller. You have to pass the `sender` which is the button. And I recommend to declare the `sender` parameter as the concrete type

```
@IBAction func detailButtonTapped(_ sender: NSButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetailsVC", sender: sender)
}
```